# pfSense, nginx reverse proxy and letsencrypt

Tags: nginx, pfsense, reverse-proxy, letsencrypt

I need help configuring letsencrypt to work with an nginx reverse proxy and pfSense firewall / gateway.

Setup is as follows:

```
                                                     ->    192.168.0.4 www (apache2)
Internet ->     pfSense      ->    rproxy (nginx)    |
            1.2.3.4 (public)        192.168.0.3      ->    192.168.0.5 mail (apache2)
```

I can connect to www and mail using http / port 80, but I need https.

1. How to set up nginx for https reverse proxy, my current setup is simple:

   ```
   server {
           listen 80;
           server_name www.domain.ovh;
           location / {
                    proxy_pass https://192.168.0.4:80;
           }
   }

   server {
           listen 80;
           server_name mail.domain.ovh;
           location / {
                proxy_pass https://192.168.0.5:80;
           }
   }
   ```
2. How to get letsencrypt to work with this setup.
   I also use letsencrypt for smtp / imap so the certs need to be on the mail host.

I have my own dns server behind pfsense that I have full control of. Domain names resolve over the internet with no issues.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks a lot ;-) everything looks good.